# why 110v psu damaged by 220volt?

Tags: power-supply

I have changed the damaged capacitor and resistor and still i have DC and AC power on the bridge  ,in addition i have around 155 DC v power on the cap,but still no light on the display of the printer whose model is hp Learjet 5200?

Comment: HP do Learjets too now?

Comment: Huh? What? - - -

Comment: To answer your title: because 220volt not 110v. To answer your question: ???

Comment: i know it is so old printer

Comment: No, the problem is that you are not saying anything relevant to help you. We haven't a smidge of a clue of what you are even talking about.

Comment: when we insert 220v AC in to 110v psu of printer .it goes off ?this is my q?

Comment: Lets rewind a little. Why does it surprise you that connecting a 110V power supply to 220V causes it to be damaged? Its rated at 110V for a reason. You exceeded its design specification, and it died.

Comment: If you're driving down the road at 220 miles per hour, with no brakes, and you suddenly come upon a 110 mile per hour curve, what do you think will happen?

Answer (score 4):

If this is like many switching supplies there is a doubler configuration at the input so you'd expect to see about 300VDC across two series capacitors. Regardless, by applying double the input voltage the hapless user will have easily exceeded the limits on several parts.

I would expect the damage to go beyond the capacitor and extend at least to the BJT or MOSFET power semiconductors. Those will have to be replaced. Chances are that if you see a sensible high voltage supply that there is also a blown fuse or traces blown off the board, and when those are repaired they will immediately blow again (perhaps causing more damage at the same time, especially if the repair is 'better'). Power semiconductors tend to either go short or physically pop (explode, chunks of epoxy flung off, etc.).

Since you mention aircraft, in aircraft terms this would be comparable to a 'prop strike'- a severe event that requires major parts to be properly replaced.

Comment: Tnx  I have found that the transformer has been burn.

Comment: Sad, but not surprising. Thanks for the feedback and post-mortem.